# Pymongo, connection pooling and asynchronous tasks via Celery

Tags: python, django, connection-pooling, celery, pymongo

I'm using pymongo to access mongodb in an application that also uses Celery to perform many asynchronous tasks. I know pymongo's connection pooling does not support asynchronous workers (based on the docs).

To access collections I've got a Collection class wrapping certain logic that fits my application. I'm trying to make sense of some code that I inherited with this wrapper:

- Each collection at the moment creates its own Connection instance. Based on what I'm reading this is wrong and I should really have a single Connection instance (in settings.py or such) and import it into my Collection instances. That bit is clear. Is there a guideline as far as the maximum connections recommended? The current code surely creates a LOT of connections/sockets as its not really making use of the pooling facilities.
- However, as some code is called from both asynchronous celery tasks as well as being run synchronously, I'm not sure how to handle this. My thought is to instantiate new Connection instances for the tasks and use the single one for for the synchronous ones (ending_request of course after each activity is done). Is this the right direction?

Thanks!

Harel

Answer (score 0):

From pymongo's docs : "PyMongo is thread-safe and even provides built-in connection pooling for threaded applications."

The word "asynchronous" in your situation can be translated into how "inconsistent" requirements your application has.

Statements like "x += 1" will never be consistent in your app. If you can afford this, there is no problem. If you have "critical" operations you must somehow implement some locks for synchronization.

As for the maximum connections, I don't know exact numbers, so test and proceed.

Also take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io) and this [example](http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html), if speed and memory efficiency are required. From some benchmarks I made, Redis python driver is at least 2x faster than pymongo, for reads/writes.